# PhoneGap error when compiling locally

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova, ant

I did the following and I am getting the error message

- I installed Apache Ant using the command **npm install apache ant**
- I updated my Cordova to the latest version, 3.4.0 by the command **npm -g update phonegap**
- I updated the system variables so the /bin directory of Java SDK and the /bin of Apache Ant is included in the PATH
- I updated my Android SDK and included Google API Ver 19

And I am still getting the following error message!  You can open the image on new tab or save the image so you can view the message more clearly

I tried running check_reqs and it only gave me one line which was

**"An error occuured while listing Android targets"**

[image: My error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I updated my Cordova to the latest version, 3.4.0 by the command npm -g update phonegap"

Cordova and PhoneGap are two different things in terms of command line clients. Have you run `npm -g install cordova`? You need to have both for the phonegap client to work with local builds.